# When using Redux, what are the features in React itself that won't be needed?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

The concept of React component state was not mentioned at all when I was going over a Redux tutorial, are there any other features in React that I can do without?

Answer (score 1):

React and Redux are separate libraries, and Redux can be used with any view layer (React, Angular, Vue, Ember, jQuery, etc).  So, Redux's tutorial focuses on just Redux's main ideas, and has [a separate page that talks about using React with Redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html).

Even if you're using React and Redux together, Redux doesn't completely "replace" React's component state - see the [Redux FAQ on using Redux state vs React component state](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html#organizing-state-only-redux-state).

Comment: What is "replace?"

Comment: In other words, you _can_ put every single value in your entire application into the Redux store (thus "replacing" use of React component state), but that's an overkill approach.  A typical Redux app will keep app-wide concerns like fetched data and possibly some high-level UI values like "is the sidebar open?" in the Redux store, but would still use React component state for things that the rest of the app doesn't care about.

Comment: Is it gonna clash with the redux-stored state? For example, how are you going to initialize the default state of a component if they are in 2 different places?

Comment: For example, a dropdown might get its list of data from the Redux store as props via `connect()`, but have `this.state = {dropdownOpen : false}` in its constructor.

Comment: Under the hood, connect doesn't utilize the native react component state? Because if it does, the way you initialize the state would be an overwriting problem.

Comment: I'm afraid you seem to be very confused on how Redux, React-Redux, and `connect` work. The key is that `connect` produces wrapper components that pass the extracted store data down to your "real" component as props. Whatever state you put in your own component is left alone. You may want to look at Dan Abramov's [miniature version of `connect`](https://gist.github.com/gaearon/1d19088790e70ac32ea636c025ba424e), which illustrates the basic approach.  I'm a Redux maintainer - trust me when I say I know what I'm talking about, and your concerns are misguided.

Comment: I never said I don't trust you, that's why I'm asking.